# Direct proof for "If for every sequence $(x_n)$ such that $\lim x_n = a$ it's true that $\lim f(x_n) = f(a)$, then $f$ is continuous"

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, alternative-proof

I already proved it by contradiction in the following way:

Negating $\lim_{x \to a} f(x) = f(a)$ assures the existence of $\epsilon>0$ such that $\forall n \in \mathbb{N}$ we can find $x_n \in X$ such that $0<|x_n-a| < 1/n \to 0$, but also $|f(x_n) - f(a)| \ge \epsilon$, which implies  $\lim x_n = a,$ without $\lim f(x_n) = f(a)$, contradiction.

I'm looking for a *direct* proof of this result.

Comment: I believe there is no direct proof of this result. By "direct", I mean a proof which can be carried out without the law of excluded middle or the axiom of choice (but possibly using dependent choice). I'll get back to you if I come up with a proof that there is no direct proof.

Comment: @MarkSaving I guess there is. Can't we phrase things in terms of closed sets, i.e. preimages of closed sets are closed? Then in sequential spaces (what we anyway need to assume for the statement to be true), we only need to check closedness for sequences and we are in business. I.e. pick $f:X\rightarrow Y$ sequentially continuous and pick $A\subseteq Y$ closed. We need to show that $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed. So let $(a_n)_{n\geq 1}\subseteq f^{-1}(A)$ be a converging sequence and let $a=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} a_n$. Then we have $(f(a_n))_{n\geq 1}\subseteq f(f^{-1}(A))\subseteq A$.

Comment: +1: good question. Could you clarify what $X$ is? I would have expected it to be a metric space, but you are using absolute value notation for the distances.

Comment: However, we have by assumption that $(f(a_n))_{n\geq 1}$ is convergent and that $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(a_n)=f(a)$. But $A$ is closed, thus $f(a)=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} f(a_n)\in A$. Thus, $a\in f^{-1}(A)$ and hence $f^{-1}(A)$ is closed.